# Why does CockroachDB fail to start?

Tags: cockroachdb

Starting up CockroachDB (with `cockroach start)` we see the start-up ends failing with the following stack trace inside the cockroach.log file:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [3] with length 3
goroutine 83 [running]:
github.com/elastic/gosigar.(*FileSystemList).Get.func1({0xc0019b8ab0, 0xc000ae9000})
    github.com/elastic/gosigar/external/com_github_elastic_gosigar/sigar_linux_common.go:113 +0x1b0
github.com/elastic/gosigar.readFile({0x4e8860e, 0x200000003}, 0xc000ac7440)
    github.com/elastic/gosigar/external/com_github_elastic_gosigar/sigar_linux_common.go:386 +0x208
github.com/elastic/gosigar.(*FileSystemList).Get(0xc000ac7508)
    github.com/elastic/gosigar/external/com_github_elastic_gosigar/sigar_linux_common.go:106 +0x8f
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage.getFileSystemProperties({0x6355138, 0xc000828e40}, {0xc00095f2f0, 0x21})
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage/store_properties.go:60 +0x1d4
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage.computeStoreProperties({0x6355138, 0xc000828e40}, {0xc00095f2f0, 0x3d}, 0x47, 0x59)
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage/store_properties.go:35 +0xa6
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage.NewPebble({0x6355138, 0xc000828e40}, {{{{0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, {0xc00095f2f0, 0x21}, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3ea35947, ...}, ...})
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/storage/pebble.go:831 +0x76d
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/server.(*Config).CreateEngines(0xc000bbf100, {0x6355138, 0xc000828e40})
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/server/config.go:649 +0x13c8
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/server.NewServer({{0xc000860000, 0xc000580b60, 0xc000151770, 0xc000a74af0, 0xc000a06300, 0xc000a062e8, {0xc000151770, {0x62ab9c0, 0xc000a74af0}, 0x0, ...}, ...}, ...}, ...)
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/server/server.go:204 +0x48a
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli.runStart.func3.2(0xc000a725a0, 0xc000485400, 0xc000417a10, {0x6355138, 0xc0019b6150}, 0x1, {0xd40b1b, 0xeda857abd, 0x0})
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli/start.go:613 +0x95
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli.runStart.func3()
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli/start.go:669 +0xf6
created by github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli.runStart
    github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/cli/start.go:584 +0x7c5
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when if there you entries in your /etc/mtab without options inside, for example due to docker. Starting cockroach before starting docker will workaround this problem. An upstream issue is open for this problem https://github.com/elastic/gosigar/issues/166.